# Line breaks in alert box are not working

Tags: javascript

I am a student and part of my college assignment I have to create a quiz using javascript.

At the end of the quiz I need to tell the user how many questions the answered correctly, and show them what the correct answers were.

I have decided to do this in an alert box (I'm sure there is a better/nicer way of doing this but I am very new to coding so I'm not very confident in this field yet).

The only problem being that when I am trying to include line breaks so the answers display in a nice way, it's not working. Please can someone review the below coding and offer some advice or point me in the direction of a good tutorial? I've read some topics on here and tried W3Schools but nothing seems to be working.

```
alert("Out of a score of 8 your score is" + score + "\n The correct answers are" + "\n 1c - A method for skipping over long lists of links or other lengthy content")
```

Answer (score 2):

The line breaks are fine. I suspect score is not defined properly.

New lines work as evidenced in this demo:

```js
var score = 100;
alert("Out of a score of 8 your score is" + score + "\n The correct answers are" + "\n 1c - A method for skipping over long lists of links or other lengthy content")
```

Comment: If I remove everything else and just include the below, my scoring works fine. Do you still think that is the issue though? Thanks for the quick reply

alert("Out of a score of 8 your score is" + score)

Comment: 1) What browser are you using? 2) Can you reproduce the error by editing my JSFiddle?

Comment: I am using Chrome and silly question but I am new to all this so what would I do to edit the JSFiddle you posted? Post in all my html code and JavaScript code? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Just the JavaScript part. You add whatever code you want to try and click run. This will let you see how my working example is different than yours.

Comment: When I entered my code in and tried to run it, it came up with a new error.... {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Comment: Please update the original question with the faulty code example. You can use the inlined code editor if you prefer instead of jsfiddle. Just click the code icon or ctrl+m